# Is it possible to restrict Google OAuth to only access user's 'sub' ID, not email/profile?

Tags: oauth-2.0, google-oauth, openid-connect

I relying on Google oauth for users to sign in to my service. I only need a way to uniquely identify the user so the [Google id (`sub`)](https://developers.google.com/identity/openid-connect/openid-connect#:%7E:text=Google%20ID%20tokens.-,sub,-always:%7E:text=Google%20ID%20tokens.-,sub,An%20identifier%20for%20the%20user%2C,-unique%20among%20all) is enough and `email`/`profile` is unnecessary. The consent screen looks the same whether I use only the `openid` scope or all three `openid email profile`.

I would like to ensure the user that I am only accessing the Google id and not email/profile. Is that possible?

If not, I'm curious why that is the case.